# How can I find the P matrix in $P^{-1}AP $= D?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following exercise:

Let a matrix A = $\begin{pmatrix}
4 & 0  & 1\\ 
 2 & 2  & 1\\ 
 0 & 4   & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$

1) Determine its eigenvalues and their multiplicity.

2) Give a basis of the eigen spaces associated with each of the
distinct eigenvalues of A.

3) find P and D such that $P^{-1}AP$ = D is diagonal.

I've done 1) and 2) and found the basis

B ={ $\begin{pmatrix}
-1 \\ 
-1 \\ 
4  
\end{pmatrix}$ , $\begin{pmatrix}
-2 \\ 
1 \\ 
4  
\end{pmatrix}$ , $\begin{pmatrix}
-1 \\ 
1 \\ 
1 
\end{pmatrix}$ }

Now, in my notes they say that the matrix P is constituted of the vectors of the basis found.

So, P = $\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & -2  & -1\\ 
 -1 & 1  & 1\\ 
 4 & 4   & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$

Also, because we have a 3x3 matrix and we've found three distinct eigen values, the matrix D exists and as such we put the eigen values on the diagonal line of the matrix. ($E_(\lambda_1) = 0$, $E_(\lambda_2) = 2$, $E_(\lambda_3) = 5$ )

D = $\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0  & 0\\ 
 0 & 2  & 0\\ 
 0 & 0   & 5 
\end{pmatrix}$

Finally to verify that this is all true I compute $AP = PD$. However I didn't find the same result on the left side and the right side of the equation. **Where did I go wrong?**

$AP \ne PD$

$\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & -4 &-3\\
 0 & 2  & 1 \\
 0 & 8  & 5 \\
\end{pmatrix} \ne \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & -4 &-5 \\
 0 & 2 & 5 \\
 0 & 8 & 5 \\
\end{pmatrix} $

Comment: $\begin{pmatrix}-1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}$ is not an eigenvector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got the last eigenvector wrong.

If you take $A$ and multiply with $(-1,1,1)$ you will get $(-3,1,5)$.

I believe you need to take $(1,1,1)$ instead. Then everything will work.

Good Luck!

Comment: Clearly so, since all of the row sums of $A$ are equal.

Answer (score 2):

A quick look at your calculations, I think your last eigen vector is wrong. The last eigen vector is (1, 1, 1) and not (-1, 1, 1). I think that would solve your problem.